# Split a list before a slash appears in an element for Python

Tags: python, list, split, slice

I have a list

```
list = ['09/30', '16:30','A','B','5','100','10/01','16:30','C','D','4',
'10/02','16:30','E','F']
```

I want it split into a new list every time before the elements with the /.

Looking to have something like this:

```
list = ['09/30', '16:30','A','B','5','100'], ['10/01','16:30','C','D','4'], ['10/02','16:30','E','F']
```

I would then like to fill in the shorter lists with NAs

```
list = [['09/30', '16:30','A','B','5','100'], ['10/01','16:30','C','D','4', 'NA'], ['10/02','16:30','E','F', 'NA', 'NA]]
```

I'm sure this is simple and I'm just missing it.

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Please show what you have done to try to achieve this.

Comment: Your final result is not valid, you need another `[]` around the list.

Comment: Adding the `NA` is easy. Get the maximum length of all the lists. Then go through all the lists, adding `max_length - len(item)` copies of `NA` to the end of each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive elements under the same "slash" element. Then get the maximum length of a group and append "NA" to the others less than that.

```
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest

class SlashGrouper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.group_id = 0

    def __call__(self, text):
        if "/" in text:
            self.group_id += 1
        return self.group_id


my_list = ['09/30', '16:30','A','B','5','100','10/01','16:30','C','D','4', '10/02','16:30','E','F']
my_list_grouped = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(my_list, key=SlashGrouper())]
print(my_list_grouped)

max_len = len(max(my_list_grouped, key=lambda val: len(val)))
for group in my_list_grouped:
    group.extend(["NA"] * (max_len - len(group)))
print(my_list_grouped)
```

**Output**

```
[['09/30', '16:30', 'A', 'B', '5', '100'], ['10/01', '16:30', 'C', 'D', '4'], ['10/02', '16:30', 'E', 'F']]
[['09/30', '16:30', 'A', 'B', '5', '100'], ['10/01', '16:30', 'C', 'D', '4', 'NA'], ['10/02', '16:30', 'E', 'F', 'NA', 'NA']]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I knew it was a simpler solution. Just couldn't get my head in it.

Comment: I have upvoted as it taught me something too, however I did note the OP for some reason has not shown any work yet; therefore downvoted the question itself.